# Win Key being treated as Hyper when I want it as Super

Tags: release-freya, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently changed from Arch to Elementary, and use emacs for all my programming, in Arch I had configured Caps Lock as Hyper, Windows Key as Super.

In elementary Os through the keyboard settings I configured caps lock as Hyper, but then realized windows key seems to default to also hyper instead of super like most distros do, or at least emacs is receiving a hyper modifier when I press win key, and there's no keyboard configuration to make it super, this is basically removing a whole keyboard of possible shortcuts for emacs.

Is there something I'm missing? How can I make Win key work as super? (s-[whatever]) in emacs)

Also, setting caps lock as "additional super" does the same thing as "additional hyper". Freya doesn't seem to distinguish between the two?

Comment: I know this is not a complete answer but maybe it helps you to find it:

I use `xmodmap` command to map my capslock key to mouse button 2 (helpful in pasting commands from websites in terminal).

In my case the commands looks like that

    `xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Pointer_Button2"`

You can use `xev` command to find out what keycode your caps lock and windows key have. Just start it in terminal with `xev`, type windows and caps lock keys and remember their keycodes. In my case win has keycode 133 and caps lock 66.

Comment: Here is another thread that may help for re-mapping keys: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7889/use-macos-style-modifier-keys