# Use macOS-style modifier keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using a Macintosh-style keyboard with Loki and would like my modifier keys to work as they do in OS X. That is, I would like:

- to copy, paste, new window with Super (Cmd) by default and not Ctrl
- option/alt and the arrow keys to jump whole words
- essentially the shortcuts as the OS X column says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Text_editing)

I thought that by choosing the "English (Macintosh)" keyboard layout that this would happen automatically—would that be a bug or a feature request? Is there any elementary OS-internal way to activate this? If not, what is the easiest external tool that already has a profile/config set up for this use case?

Comment: Post this to Launchpad so it can be added to wishlist.

Comment: Here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1624189

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I futzed around with this for a day (gsettings, built-in shortcuts, xkb, xmodmap) and no turnkey solution is forthcoming, though I [filed a feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1624189) that might lead somewhere.

In the meantime and short of rewriting the actual system shortcuts (which is the longterm solution), I'll try to list what I felt was the best way to approximate the OS X experience in elementary OS. Remember the idea is not to simply make the Super/Command key a clone of the Control key (the Control key has its own specific uses in Terminal and elsewhere).

#### Repurpose existing shortcuts

When a shortcut already is in use but just needs to be mapped to the familiar shortcut, AutoKey is the fastest solution for now. I suggest the following remaps (install directions follow the list):

```
<ctrl>+C  ⌘+C     copy
<ctrl>+V  ⌘+V     paste
<ctrl>+N  ⌘+N     new window
<ctrl>+T  ⌘+T     new tab
<ctrl>+W  ⌘+W     close window

<ctrl>+Z  ⌘+Z     undo
<ctrl>+F  ⌘+F     find
<ctrl>+A  ⌘+A     select all text
```

skip between... (for each, remember to add both left/right up/down pairs and to add highlight versions by adding `<shift>` as a separate entry)

```
<ctrl>+<left>  <alt>+<left>   words
<ctrl>+<up>  <alt>+<up>       paragraphs
<home>  <super>+<left>        go to beginning of line
<end>  <super>+<right>        go to end of line
<ctrl>+<home>  <super>+<up>   go to top of text
<ctrl>+<end>  <super>+<down>  go to bottom of text
```

To install:

1. `sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk`
2. Open AutoKey from the Applications drawer
3. Add "New" item and put the existing shortcut in the text field (e.g., `<ctrl>+T`)
4. Set the hotkey (e.g., press Cmd+T, which will show as `<super>+T`)
5. Keep the rest of the defaults and repeat

You'll need to deactivate the shortcut conflicts with the Keyboard preference pane, or use these:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings expose-windows "['<Super><Alt>w']"
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings expose-all-windows "['<Super><Alt>A']"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver ''
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal "['<Alt><Super>t']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings show-desktop "['<Alt><Super>Down']"
```

This solution might not behave as expected in all applications, but this is only jury-rigged until someone fills [the feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1624189) on Launchpad.

Comment: I understand that it is impossible to assign Cmd+Space to switching layouts.

Comment: @MaximTaranov, do you mean switching keyboard layouts? Or turning all of the above settings on/off? You can unmap Cmd+Space with Keyboard > Applications > Applications Launcher and reassign it as you please

Comment: I mean switching keyboard layouts, Loki doesn't support this shortcut for switching layouts, but this shortcut uses in macOS. You can see available shortcuts [here](https://github.com/GNOME/mutter/blob/master/src/core/keybindings.c) (using `g_str_equal (iso_next_group_option` phrase in the search).

Comment: @MaximTaranov, https://medium.com/@andv/making-elementary-os-changing-keyboard-layout-with-super-space-8b1cb6385465#.nkhth47uq

Comment: @wolf Having some trouble following your install steps. Am I adding a new 'script' in AutoKey? Wondering if I'm in the right tool: 
https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/34b4d7303ec0532fcb14ad3c37e17d3b.png

Comment: @ElleryFamilia yep! "new phrase" is for simple text insertion, and "new script" is for when you want to trigger code

Comment: @ElleryFamilia Please see my blog post for a complete set of Autokey hotkeys: https://yimd.net/in-the-quest-of-finding-an-open-macos/

Comment: @wolf i'm also running eOS on a MBP - what's your battery life like? Mine is terrible, about 4 hours (and i'm used to 10!). I think it's due to the graphics card...did you figure out anything about that?

Comment: Everything works great except for when I use ⌘+V to paste I always get a leading or trailing character "v" with the pasted text. Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: @Sayan I haven't had that issue in a while but I think it's an AutoKey thing. Try updating to the latest version and quitting out of previous instances?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to switch the Left Alt and Left Ctrl locations.  I was able to accomplish this by installing the Gnome Tweak tool and adjust it under the typing settings.  I think so longs as your not adjusting anything else in the gnome tweak tool you should be fine.