# Where are the keyboard shortcuts stored?

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts

When I create a custom keyboard shortcut in Loki, where is that stored?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a GUI feature for this. It looks like someone with a similar question found a solution [on this forum here.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7889/use-macos-style-modifier-keys)