# How to get cursor text navigation like MacOS - cmd(ctrl) for end/start of line, option(alt) for next/prev word

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I'm using ElementaryOS 6 on my main desktop computer and looking for text cursor navigation like MacOS.

**Example:** When you hold `cmd` and left or right arrow keys, it navigates to the beginning/end of the line vs holding `option` with arrow keys navigates to next/previous word/section/.

I've looked into packages that completely overhaul the keyboard shortcuts (like Kinto) but I like most of the other defaults ElementaryOS offers. Is there a way to do this without completely changing the keyboard mapping.

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7946/25612)? It's a few years old, but may give you what you're looking for 

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the post @matigo linked still works. However, because I found the explanation in that post a little unclear, I wanted to spell out what I did.

[Autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) is easy to set up and will give the desired result. Note that Autokey does not change the bindings; rather, it runs in the background and intercepts keyboard shortcuts and then maps them to specified shortcuts.
Install Autokey from the Ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

Then launch the Application Menu and select Autokey. Click on Edit > Preferences and check the box for “Automatically start Autokey at login.”

Now you can specify the mappings. Click New > Phrase and give the new item a name. In the text box where it says “enter phrase contents” type the keyboard shortcut you want to map to. For example, `<home>`. Then click “Set” in the hotkey row, click “Press to set” and then you can type the key combination you want to map from. Finally, click “Save” and repeat for all desired keyboard mappings.

To get the combinations you asked for, I created four entries and then an additional four entries with `<shift>` included to select the text. Just make sure the arrow key or end/home is always the final component of the command, or it will paste text instead of executing the shortcut.

Here are a couple examples of what my Autokey entries look like at the end.

Move cursor to beginning of line.
Text box: `<home>`
Hotkey: `<super>+<left>`

Move cursor word left and select word.
Text box: `<shift>+<ctrl>+<left>`
Hotkey: `<alt>+<shift>+<left>`

Make sure to keep "Paste Using Keyboard" selected.

Also if you replace a default shortcut, you will have to disable it. In this case, go to System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Workspaces. And disable `<super>+<left>` and `<super>+<right>`.

This seems to be working well. Though I think ideally there should be an option to make these changes this under System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts. If I don’t see a feature request on Github, I might go ahead and add one.