# Is it possible to set EOS keyboard shortcuts to be like in macOS?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macintosh

Currently I mainly use macOS and I tried EOS because it seemed so similar. However, the keyboard shortcuts were very "windows like". Is it possible to set the system so the keyboard shortcuts become equal or very similar to macOS? That would make the transition so much smoother.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just go to System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts
Then click on any keybinding you want to change & give custom keystrokes.
Like, I myself has changed "Close" from Alt+F4 to Command+Q which is traditional on a mac
N.B:- On a windows laptop command key is the super or windows key.
Upvote if this helps!

Comment: I tried doing that but there are only a few limited commands you can change. For example you can't change Copy or Paste.

Answer (score 0):

In response to another question on here, I described how to change the cursor navigation to match MacOS, using a tool called Autokey.

[How to get cursor text navigation like MacOS - cmd(ctrl) for end/start of line, option(alt) for next/prev word](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28619/how-to-get-cursor-text-navigation-like-macos-cmdctrl-for-end-start-of-line/28656#28656)